# Attribute Routing not working when Url is like this mydomain.com/directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

**I have created directory in my FTP account in which i am publishing my Project.
so URL is like this mydomain.com/directoryname.**

It works when i try to access action method using default route.

### ex.myomain.com/directoryname/customer/create          **This works**

But when i try to use attribute routing it is not working.
ex. if i specify `[Route("RegisterCustomer")]` to this action method
and i tried to access

```
myomain.com/directoryname/customer/RegisterCustomer
```

OR

```
myomain.com/directoryname/RegisterCustomer
```

Both doesn't work.

attribute routing works fine in `mydomain.com` but i need to publish project in the directory.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Did you make the directory into an IIS application?

Comment: no i made it on ftp server

Comment: What does your route config look like?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC won't run on an FTP server. You need to configure the virtual directory as an [IIS application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) for it to work.